# Validate that url has only one subdirectory

Tags: javascript

I want to cause jquery to fire if the URL is only one subdirectory long.

For example, http://milpool.com/thrillho but not http://milpool.com/thrillho/santoslhalper

I can't know the actual content of the directories.

I thought it would be something like this:

```
if (document.location.pathname.length) == 2 {
    // do something
}
```

but apparently not.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in your code...

Comment: your syntax is incorrect for an if statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.length` returns the length of the string returned by `document.location.pathname`. That's why your solution didn't work (that and the syntax error).

```
if (document.location.pathname.split(/\/(?=.)/).length == 2) {
    // do something
}
```

`pathname` always contains the initial `/` and the regex makes sure the trailing `/` is not included.

You want the result of the split to be `["", "firstDirectory"]` and therefore of length 2.

Note: Some browsers (I tested IE) can include the trailing slash so you can't use only `.split('/')`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `location.pathname.split('/').length`

Comment: Does not actually work.  Did you try your code before you posted?

Comment: Define `Does not actually work`. Open up console and see for yourself.

Comment: both `/subdir` and `/subdir/` are valid cases, your solution does not handle both.