# Check submitted URL has at least one subdirectory

Tags: javascript, url

I need to check that a submitted URL has at least one subdirectory in it.

Eg: `domain.com, domain.com/`, `domain.com/?utm=asdf` will fail, while `domain.com/asdf` , `domain.com/asdf/`, `domain.com/asdf/asdf`  etc will succeed.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you consider `domain.com/asdf` to contain a subdirectory (there's no `/` on the end, so resolving `../` from there would give you the same result as resolving `./`)? Why does "having a subdirectory" *matter*?

Comment: What result should `example.com/index.html` give?

Answer (score 1):

Creating an `<a>` element in memory helps you dissect URLs:

```js
function checkPathname(url) {
  var el = document.createElement('a');
  el.href = url;
  return el.pathname && el.pathname !== '/';
}

console.log(checkPathname('http://www.test.com?foo=bar'));         // false
console.log(checkPathname('http://www.test.com/?foo=bar'));        // false
console.log(checkPathname('http://www.test.com/foobar?foo=bar'));  // true
console.log(checkPathname('http://www.test.com/foo/bar?foo=bar')); // true
```

Comment: Thanks Timo - I went a different direction in the end, as described by the accepted answer on this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560477/validate-that-url-has-only-one-subdirectory

Thanks for your help though, much appreciated.